# Can I hide Add-Ins in the Visual Basic Editor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've recently discovered *add-ins* in Excel, and how I can use them to share code over many workbooks. However I do not always want this code to be visible. Since creating and enabling my add-in, the code now always appears in the VBE navigation pane.

For example, with my `ExcelTools` add-in enabled I now get this every time I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> to open the editor on a blank workbook

[image: My ExcelTools Addin]

Is there any way to stop my add-in code appearing here, without disabling the add-in altogether?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot hide it. Why do you want to hide the code? Maybe we can find a workaround for your requirenment.

Comment: You can lock it with password, so your "ExcelTools" could be opened only by password